# SharePoint Server 2016 components that need to be patched independently?

Tags: 2016, patching

I would like to know if I need to patch any component used by SharePoint Server 2016 that its update is not included in the monthly KBs published by Microsoft. Like for example Distributed Cache components, or any of the prerequisites that you have to install before installing SharePoint Server 2016 on servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint always patched by CU, their is no separate patches unless MSFT announced it. but their couple of independent product which can be patched independently.

1. Workflow Manager Server
2. Office Online Server
3. .Net framework
4. Windows Server
5. Distributed Cache (App Fabric) [should be patched independently of SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/server-install/installing-appfabric-updates)

Comment: What about Windows Server AppFabric, one of the prerequisites installed by the Microsoft SharePoint 2016 Products Preparation Tool? Does this one require patching?

Comment: On SP 2019 and SP 2016 when both are installed they both install AppFabric 1.1  for Windows Server CU7 KB3092423 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3092423/cumulative-update-7-for-microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server Does that mean that any updates of this component will be included in the SharePoint Server installer/patch?

Comment: Just found that AF CU8 exists and I want to know if this has to be installed on SharePoint Server 2016 and 2019 farms as part of patching this component. Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/02/02/additional-details-on-af-cu8-release/

Comment: You are right, i forget about the distributed cache, it will be patched independently of SharePoint servers.  here is article which explain it in detailed: http://www.wictorwilen.se/how-to-patch-the-distributed-cache-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thank you, but the links you have provided are for SharePoint Server 2013 and old AppFabric CUs. Could you share any articles specific to installing AppFabric CU8 on SharePoint Server 2016 and 2019?

Comment: On the other hand, in this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3199763/hotfix-3199763-is-available-for-microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-se, it mentions that AF CU8 can be installed on Windows Server 2012 R2, but does not mention Windows Server 2016 as a supported OS, which I am using for SharePoint Server 2019. How will I patch AF on that farm then?

Comment: Additional details on AF CU8 release https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/02/02/additional-details-on-af-cu8-release/